# "How can I remove the extra scripts that Next.js automatically adds to the source code page?"

Tags: next.js

When developing with Next.js, it automatically injects certain scripts into the outputted source code. These scripts often aid in the framework's functionality, but there might be instances where they are not desired. The challenge arises in determining how to safely remove these auto-generated scripts without compromising the application's performance and functionality.

I was expecting that all the scripts that are generated by Next.js on source page code should be view less.

Answer (score 0):

I think I can quite simply answer this question with: **You can't and you shouldn't**. Each script that can be seen in the rendered output of a Next.js application is required in some shape or form and thus simply can not be removed.

Question here is, why would you want to remove those scripts in the first place as well as what situations are "instances where they are not desired".